# Javascript/jQuery countdown timer not initialising correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this countdown timer that I've modified from the original however it doesn't seem to be working. The issue with it that I have highlighted is that `startCountdown(startDate,deadlineDate,expiredText)` isn't firing it returns **undefined**. Everything else in the code is firing as expected and brings back the correct results any ideas?

I've added all the information below containing console logs etc. etc.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.clockdiv').each(function() {
    //START Get required values
    var startDate = $(this).find(".start").attr("rel"); //Gets start date of offer
    var deadlineDate = $(this).find(".end").attr("rel"); //Gets deadline date of offer
    var expiredText = $(this).find(".expired").attr("rel"); //Gets expired coupon text
    //END Get required values

    function getTimeRemaining(deadlineDate, startDate) {
      var pD = Date.parse(deadlineDate); //Get the amount of milliseconds until the end date
      var pS = Date.parse(startDate); //Get the amount of milliseconds since the start date
      var t = pD - pS; //Find out how many milliseconds from start date to the deadline date
      var s = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60); //Works out how many seconds until the deadline
      var m = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60); //Works out how many minutes until the deadline
      var h = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24); //Works out how many hours until the deadline
      var d = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //Works out how many days until the deadline

      return { //Return the value of the total time remaining
        'total': t, //Return the value of the total time remaining
        'days': d, //Return the value of the days remaining
        'hours': h, //Return the value of the hours remaining
        'minutes': m, //Return the value of the minutes remaining
        'seconds': s //Return the value of the seconds remaining
      };
    }

    function startCountdown(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText) {
      var dC = $(this).find('div > .days'); //Get the days container of the clock
      var hC = $(this).find('div > .hours'); //Get the hours container of the clock
      var mC = $(this).find('div > .minutes'); //Get the minutes container of the clock
      var sC = $(this).find('div > .seconds'); //Get the seconds container of the clock

      function updateClock(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText) {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(deadlineDate, startDate); //Reassign the value of t to be the output of getTimeRemaining fuction

        dC.innerHTML = t.days; //Set the innerHTML to display the days remaining
        hC.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2); //Set the innerHTML to display the hours remaining
        mC.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2); //Set the innerHTML to display the minutes remaining
        sC.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2); //Set the innerHTML to display the seconds remaining

        if (t.total <= 0) { //If there is no time remaining then do the following
          clearInterval(clockLoop); //Stop the 1s looping of the clockLoop
          $(this).innerHTML = '<p>' + expiredText + '</p>'; //Display the expiredText value inside of the clockdiv
        }

        console.log(startDate); // 2019/07/25 13:00:00
        console.log(deadlineDate); // 2019/07/26 14:00:00
        console.log(expiredText); // Offer Expired
        console.log(t); // {total: 90000000, days: 1, hours: 1, minutes: 0, seconds: 0}
        console.log(dC); // a.fn.init [selector: "div > .days", prevObject: a.fn.init(1), context: document, innerHTML: 1]
        console.log(hC); // a.fn.init [selector: "div > .hours", prevObject: a.fn.init(1), context: document, innerHTML: "01"]
        console.log(mC); // a.fn.init [selector: "div > .minutes", prevObject: a.fn.init(1), context: document, innerHTML: "00"]
        console.log(sC); // a.fn.init [selector: "div > .seconds", prevObject: a.fn.init(1), context: document, innerHTML: "00"]
        console.log(t.total); // 90000000
        console.log(t.days); //1
        console.log(t.hours); //1
        console.log(t.minutes); //0
        console.log(t.seconds); //0
      }
      updateClock(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText); //Run the updateClock function
      console.log(updateClock(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText)); //1
      var clockLoop = setInterval(updateClock, 1000); //Define the clockLoop to run the updateClock function every second
      console.log(clockLoop); // undefined
    }

    startCountdown(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText); //Initiate the startCountdown clock
    console.log(startCountdown(startDate, deadlineDate, expiredText)); // undefined
  });
});
```

```css
#clockdiv {
    color: #74b848;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    max-width: 320px; }

#clockdiv > div {
    flex: 20%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #74b848;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv div > span {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

#clockdiv .smalltext {
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clockdiv" class="clockdiv">
  <span class="start" rel="2019/07/25 13:00:00"></span><br>
  <span class="end" rel="2019/07/26 14:00:00"></span><br>
  <span class="expired" rel="Offer Expired"></span>
  <p></p>
  <div><span id="days" class="days"></span>
    <p></p>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div><span id="hours" class="hours"></span>
    <p></p>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div><span id="minutes" class="minutes"></span>
    <p></p>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div><span id="seconds" class="seconds"></span>
    <p></p>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE: Added an alert into each of the functions to see if they triggered and they all triggered with getTimeRemaining looping every second as expected the same with updateClock. startCountdown triggered twice as expected as there are 2 clockdivs on the page.**

**UPDATE: Changing `sC.innerHTML.innerhHTML` to `document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML` displays the number for 1 second however when it then runs the function again it returns NaN.

Comment: did you break it down to see where it's breaking? like put console.log() inside the function and then also inside updateClock to make sure it is all hitting correctly?

Comment: @Keith all areas are indeed hitting correctly, it's when it gets to startCountdown that it just says undefined.

Comment: Can you add this as a snippet or on jsfiddle.net? HTML and CSS would be ideal to see where the issue is.

Comment: it would help us if you provide the related `HTML` part.

Comment: I've added all console log portions of this, css has nothing to do with this and the HTML structure has also been added for you.

Comment: I've added all console logs so you can identify inside of the function what isn't working and what is @Shilly hopefully this helps us all find the issue.

Comment: It looks like its on an endless loop. It works until the HTML runs out

Comment: Ah, so `t.total == NaN` ?

Comment: @Keith it is indeed mean't to loop indefinitely every second in order to decrease the countdown by 1 second each time.

Comment: @Shilly after testing again it does return the right value, I have 2 clockdivs on the same page read the 2nd reading not the first.

Comment: you have non-numerical values in the `rel` attributes.

Comment: @ths Date.parse turns this into a numerical format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version of it: https://jsfiddle.net/5tfd4Lsn/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.clockdiv').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        //START Get required values
        var startDate = self.find(".start").attr("rel"); //Gets start date of offer
        var deadlineDate = self.find(".end").attr("rel"); //Gets deadline date of offer
        var expiredText = self.find(".expired").attr("rel"); //Gets expired coupon text
        //END Get required values

        function getTimeRemaining(deadlineDate,startDate) {
            var pD = Date.parse(deadlineDate); //Get the amount of milliseconds until the end date
            //var pS = Date.parse(startDate); //Get the amount of milliseconds since the start date
            var pS = Date.now();
            var t = pD - pS; //Find out how many milliseconds from start date to the deadline date
            var s = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60); //Works out how many seconds until the deadline
            var m = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60); //Works out how many minutes until the deadline
            var h = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24); //Works out how many hours until the deadline
            var d = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //Works out how many days until the deadline

            return { //Return the value of the total time remaining
                'total': t, //Return the value of the total time remaining
                'days': d, //Return the value of the days remaining
                'hours': h, //Return the value of the hours remaining
                'minutes': m, //Return the value of the minutes remaining
                'seconds': s //Return the value of the seconds remaining
            };
        }

        function startCountdown(startDate,deadlineDate,expiredText) {
            var dC = self.find('div > .days'); //Get the days container of the clock
            var hC = self.find('div > .hours'); //Get the hours container of the clock
            var mC = self.find('div > .minutes'); //Get the minutes container of the clock
            var sC = self.find('div > .seconds'); //Get the seconds container of the clock

            function updateClock() {
                var t = getTimeRemaining(deadlineDate,startDate); //Reassign the value of t to be the output of getTimeRemaining fuction
                console.log(t);

                dC.empty().append($.parseHTML('' + t.days)); //Set the innerHTML to display the days remaining
                hC.empty().append($.parseHTML(('0' + t.hours).slice(-2))); //Set the innerHTML to display the hours remaining
                mC.empty().append($.parseHTML(('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2))); //Set the innerHTML to display the minutes remaining
                sC.empty().append($.parseHTML(('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2))); //Set the innerHTML to display the seconds remaining

                if (t.total <= 0) { //If there is no time remaining then do the following
                    clearInterval(clockLoop); //Stop the 1s looping of the clockLoop
                    self.empty().append($.parseHTML('<p>' + expiredText + '</p>')); //Display the expiredText value inside of the clockdiv
                }

            }
            updateClock(); //Run the updateClock function
            var clockLoop = setInterval(updateClock, 1000); //Define the clockLoop to run the updateClock function every seond
        }

        startCountdown(startDate,deadlineDate,expiredText); //Initiate the startCountdown clock
     });
});
```

- The main problem is that your updateClock function expects parameters, but it will not receive any parameters when the timer callback is issued.  You should just use the local variables from the closure.
- The way you had it set up, it was always calculating the time remaining based on a static startDate.  It makes more sense to use the system time (var pS = Date.now()), so you'll actually see it change.
- You can't rely on the "this" parameter still referencing your .clockdiv within the timer callback.  I fixed this by saving it in a local variable called "self".
- I don't think you can simply assign stuff to an innerHTML attribute of a jQuery object and have it do what you expect.  I usually use $(whatever).empty().append($.parseHTML(...)).  That uses jQuery methods to clear out any existing DOM elements and then append the DOM from the parsed HTML to the specified element.  There are probably other ways to do it.

Comment: I am actually stupid, why the heck did I have it in my mind that start date was at all relevant. Thanks for sorting that out, I just had cottoned onto the self and innerHTML issue so glad to see I was on the right tracks.